# Is anyone interested in a voting contest?

Tags: discussion, voting, contests

Mark and I were discussing on this question, [How close are we to coming out of beta?](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/502/how-close-are-we-to-coming-out-of-beta), what things we would need to do to get closer to coming out of beta.

We're doing great, but if we graduated today, we would only have 6 regular users who are close voters, assuming the 3 elected moderators were from the 3K+ pool of users. This is not enough people to effectively community moderate the site.

To solve this problem, we need more good users who can edit posts (2K+ users) and more users who can vote to close/reopen (3K+ users on graduated sites). we have a lot of good users who are below these thresholds who would make great editors and close/reopen voters.

I see that there's a lot of great content on the site, and I see that this content could be voted up even higher if more people were to commit to using all of their votes.

I was thinking that a cool way to get more people voting would be to have a contest of some kind surrounding the voting badges:

- [Vox Populi](https://pm.stackexchange.com/badges/66/vox-populi): Used the maximum 40 votes in a day. (3 users hold this badge)
- [Suffrage](https://pm.stackexchange.com/badges/57/suffrage): Used 30 votes in a day. (15 users hold this badge)
- [Civic Duty](https://pm.stackexchange.com/badges/18/civic-duty):  Voted 300 or more times (7 users hold this badge)
- [Sportsmanship](https://pm.stackexchange.com/badges/58/sportsmanship): Up voted 100 answers on questions where an answer of yours has a positive score

We'd need some rules and guidelines, of course, criteria for how to pick winners, what sorts of prizes would be involved, etc. Is anyone interested in helping or participating in something like this?

Comment: We'd just have to keep a close eye on sockpuppetry and so forth. An event like this would be a sock's dream.

Comment: Right. Good point ;) @Aarthi, I might drop by TL later to brainstorm if a voter-focused contest would possibly still attract socks. My thought was focus on votes, not the rep, but I haven't completely thought through this yet either. ;)

Comment: @Aarthi Any other sites you could point to that have done this successfully?

Comment: @MarkPhillips To be honest, I can't think of any sites that have done this successfully. We usually tamp down on these kinds of contests because (1) reputation is (effectively) sacred, and (2) the threat of socks alone is a big enough headache to dissuade most. If you'd like, I can bring this up with the team.

Comment: @Aarthi - We can brainstorm other contest ideas as well, as the thought of vote fraud makes me ill.  It's also important that people are actually interested in participating in whatever we propose, so before I'd seriously put any energy into any contest idea or taking up your time with discussions about it, I'd want people in our community to be excited about the idea. If we do get people excited about such a community building activity, we'll be sure to include you and the community team in our discussions. ;)

Comment: Hey @jmort253 I really liked this post on [boardgames.se] check it out: http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/918/what-can-you-do-for-bcg

Comment: What happened to this idea finally  ?

Comment: Hi @AshRj. Most contests require input and participation from members of the community. It didn't seem like there was much interest in this. Also, because of the concerns about voting fraud, I abandoned the idea and stopped pushing on it. However, if someone has a good idea for a contest or event that would help engage the community, you're welcome to propose the idea here and discuss in the [chat].  If the idea is something people are interested in, I'm happy to help it succeed! :)

Comment: @jmort253 Actually, I was asking because I am a Pro Tem [Mod](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/users/189/ashrj) on [reverseengineering.se] and was thinking of something along similar lines :-)

Comment: @AshRj - [Super User](http://superuser.com) has had good success with contests, as has [Bicycling](http://bicycling.stackexchange.com). You may want to check with those communities and see how things went. Also, check [Board and Card Games SE](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/918/what-can-you-do-for-bcg).  The first two are graduated sites with larger communities while the latter is a beta site. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I will look at those sites. Thanks :-)